# Find existing object into an array in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

Hi this is my collection i just want to look userId into subcriber array if both userId exist into the subcriber array than not create new collection return same channelId. If both userId not exist into subcriber array then create new document how can i search userids in an array.
this is my collection.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58dd1013e973fc0004743443"),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2017-03-30T14:02:59.175Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-03-30T14:02:59.175Z"),
"timestamp" : "2017-03-30",
"channelId" : "CH-EU7D",
"createdById" : "58dcc3cd9a7a301308b62857",
"message" : "",
"subcriber" : [ 
    {
        "userId" : "58dcc3cd9a7a301308b62857",
        "channelId" : "CH-EU7D",
        "_id" : ObjectId("58dd1013e973fc0004743444"),
        "status" : "accepted"
    }, 
    {
        "userId" : "58dcc3ec9a7a301308b62859",
        "channelId" : "CH-EU7D",
        "_id" : ObjectId("58dd1013e973fc0004743445"),
        "status" : "pending"
    }
],
"__v" : 0
```

}

I have tried this but not working.

```
Channel.find({ 'subcriber.userId': b.userId }, { $and: [{ 'subcriber.userId': b.friendId }] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nodejs you can use JavaScript [**Array.prototype.some()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method with your json array to test if there's any matching `useId`, you will need to write something like:

```
function checkUserId(array, userId) {
  return array.some(function(element) {
    return userId === element.userId;
  });
}
```

This is a Demo snippet:

```js
function checkUserId(array, userId) {
  return array.some(function(element) {
    return userId === element.userId;
  });
}


var json = {
  "_id": "58dd1013e973fc0004743443",
  "createdAt": "2017-03-30T14:02:59.175Z",
  "updatedAt": "2017-03-30T14:02:59.175Z",
  "timestamp": "2017-03-30",
  "channelId": "CH-EU7D",
  "createdById": "58dcc3cd9a7a301308b62857",
  "message": "",
  "subcriber": [{
      "userId": "58dcc3cd9a7a301308b62857",
      "channelId": "CH-EU7D",
      "_id": "58dd1013e973fc0004743444",
      "status": "accepted"
    },
    {
      "userId": "58dcc3ec9a7a301308b62859",
      "channelId": "CH-EU7D",
      "_id": "58dd1013e973fc0004743445",
      "status": "pending"
    }
  ]
};

//Check an existing userId
console.log(checkUserId(json.subcriber, "58dcc3ec9a7a301308b62859"));

//Check a non existing userId
console.log(checkUserId(json.subcriber, "58dcc3ec9a7a3000000000859"));
```

Answer (score 1):

for this type of problem can use $elemMatch of mongodb.

```
db.getCollection('channels').find({subcriber:{"$elemMatch":{userId:"58dcc3cd9a7a301308b62857",userId:'58dcc3ec9a7a301308b62859'}}})
```